# Show all attributes

Tags: commerce

I need All my attributes to display on the page.
Like this: https://www.lowa.ca/fr/produit/renegade-gtx-mid/

So if you select a color, you still see all sizes. With their availability
Also if you select a size, the available colors are available to click for that size.

Do you have any clue on implementing this on Commerce 8.x.2.36?